# Export from DataGrid to Excel with Interop is too slow

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, interop

I'm about to write a WPF application that takes data from database and displays it in DataGrid. Then with a button an Excel file is created and filled with the data. With large quantities like 20000 lines the filling in Excel takes too long. Does someone have an idea why? Thank you

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        DataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
        DataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, DataGrid1);

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
    }
```

Comment: VBA Automation in dot NET is not very efficiant :(

Comment: Hi Sion thank you very much for the answer, but why VBA ? I write C# Code not VBA(Visua Basic for Aplication) Best Regards

Comment: Hi @Yves, Did you try OpenXml and check the performance?

Comment: `...new Excel.Application();` is really a mask to the old fashioned OLE COM automation using **NET Interop**, which seems to be a heavy creature :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I am using currently.
But this is much similar to your code. But I am using a data object to copy the content to clipboard. This works really fine for me. But a number of lines like 20000 will anyway affect the performances.

```
    private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       copyDataGridToClipboard();
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
       object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
       xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       xlexcel.Visible = true;
       xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
       xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
       CR.Select();
       xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true); 
   }
   private void copyDataGridToClipboard()
   {
      YourDataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
      yourDataGridView.SelectAll();
      DataObject dataObj = yourDataGridView.GetClipboardContent();
      if (dataObj != null)
      {
          Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
      }
      yourDataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
   }
```