# Copying WPF DataGrid to Clipboard takes too long

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datagrid

I wrote a WPF application that copies data from DataGrid to the Clipboard and then automatically pastes it into Excel. The problem: Copying takes much too long. Are there other ways to copy DataGrid to Clipboard faster?Thanks

```
 private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        DataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
        DataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, DataGrid1); // Take too long time
    }



    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
    }
```

Comment: How about the answer to [your previous, very similar if not identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52832292/1136211)?

Answer (score 1):

I think one Problem is that you copy from the UI, rather then the raw data from the code behind. And I see some other stuff to indicate that you are not using the MVVM pattern. WPF/UWP and XAML were practically designed for the MVVM pattern. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issues at every other place. If you plan on staying on that GUI technology, there is no excuse not to learn MVVM first and probably solve your issues along the way.

If the operation takes long and that can not be fixed, it might be time to think about some Multitasking. Basically this Operation (Export to Excel) takes long. And if you got a long running operation of any kind (Saving to disk, printing, Exporting to another Format) that usually calls for some Multitasking.

Comment: Thank you very much